# Erro 550 ao excluir um diretório via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Estou usando FileZilla. Segue o erro ao tentar deletar uma pasta:

> Resposta: 550 Could not delete 33: Invalid argument

Segui um [tutorial para upload de imagens](http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL), a diferença é que eu criei uma pasta com o id do usuário e dentro dela há as imagens que ele fez upload.

No FTP, setei a permissão do diretório principal de imagens como 777

[image]

Deve-se fazer algo para setar a criação da pasta como readable e deletable via código, não é? O código do exemplo criou no servidor pastas que não podem ser deletadas e nem vistas.

Answer (score 1):

Confime se o usuário que o php esta executando é o mesmo que você logou no ftp. Use:

```php
<?php
$userid = posix_geteuid();
$userInfo = posix_getpwuid($userid);
var_dump($userInfo);
```

Se o usuário for diferente, pode ocorrer de você não consegui deletar por não ser dono da pasta, já que ela foi criada com o php, ai será preciso logar com o usuário que o php estiver rodando.

Comment: colei esse código no php, o que eu faço agora? saiu uma array com nome, senha,uid etc

Comment: confere se o nome de usuario desse array é o mesmo usuário que vc está logando no ftp